# System 1 (fast and unconscious) thinking

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, experimental-psychology, experiment-design, experimental-neuroscience

Can you please recommend some literature about experiments used to study system 1 (fast and unconscious) decision making (Kahneman, 2011) in human or non-human animals?

**Reference**

Kahneman, D. (2011). Thinking, fast and slow. Macmillan. ISBN 9780141033570

Comment: I've not read Thinking, fast and slow (Kahneman, 2011); however, reviews report that the book itself lists a wide range of experiments.  It was also evident from a broader search that the book has been heavily criticised for relying on experiments with very low statistical power.  See articles: http://retractionwatch.com/2017/02/20/placed-much-faith-underpowered-studies-nobel-prize-winner-admits-mistakes/ and https://replicationindex.com/2017/02/02/reconstruction-of-a-train-wreck-how-priming-research-went-of-the-rails/

Comment: Can you add more background information? What is System 1 thinking, why is it important and what exactly are you seeking for answers?

Comment: Have you looked at this previous response? 
 https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/10325/thinking-fast-and-slow-similarity-of-linda-problem-and-dinnerware-case?rq=1

Comment: @AliceD System 1 thinking, coined by Dan Kahneman, one of the two models of thought, which is fast and unconscious. I'm trying to find literature showing that system one thinking is developed through evolution.

Comment: @TonyMobbs That's the main source I'm reading. I'm looking for other scholars to see their perspectives. Any advice? Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Just a pointer - rather than answering requests for more information on what your asking within comments, please add that extra information into your question via an [edit]. Not everyone reads the comments and it will be more useful to have all the relevant information within your question.